# Using condition to replace value of data frame using another data frame in R

Tags: r

I am stuck in one problem and try to find the similar solution but was unable to find that here in stackoverflow. My data look like this:

```
x1 <- data.frame(x = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))

y1 <- data.frame(x = c(sin(x1 - 3.4)), y = c(cos(x1-3.2), z = tan(x1-3.5)))
```

What I want to do is to replace the value of `y1` by NA if `x1 = 0` but would like to keep the value as it is if `x1 = 1` for whole data frame `y1` at the same time. I

I tried `ifelse` function as

```
y1 <- ifelse(x1 == 0, NA, y1)
```

But I was unable to process that. If anyone can suggest me the answer without loop that would be great.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `y1[x1==0,]=NA`

Comment: Try `(NA^!x1)*y1`

Comment: There are multiple columns in your "y1" data frame. Clarify whether you'd like a particular column or single column from "y1" to be replaced with NA when applicable.

Comment: Hi Dale Kube I have multiple column and all the column of y1 should be replaced with NA

Comment: I got the answer thank you everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
y1[x1$x == 0,] <- NA
```

Note that this sets relevant rows in all columns in `y1` as `NA`. You could do this for one column only by, for example:

```
y1$x[x1$x == 0] <- NA
```

Comment: Thank you very very much for the answer.